# Exporting a mongoose database module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to export my mongoose database module, so I could use my defined models from every module in my program.

For example, my database.js module looks something like that:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/newdb'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log("Connected to database newdb");

    var dynamicUserItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      userID: Number,
      rank:  Number,
    });

    var staticUserItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    });

    var DynamicUserItem = db.model('DynamicUserItem', dynamicUserItemSchema);
    var StaticUserItem = db.model('StaticUserItem', staticUserItemSchema);

});
```

I want to be able adding `var db = require('../my_modules/database');` to any other module my program - so I will be able to use the models like that:

`db.DynamicUserItem.find();` or `item = new db.DynamicUserItem({});`

Is it possible doing that using "exports" or "module exports" ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I usually don't use the `error` and `open` events and follow the example from [mongoosejs](http://mongoosejs.com/) to create a connection to my db. Using the example you could do the following.

db.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');

var schema = mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string' });
var Cat = db.model('Cat', schema);

module.exports = Cat; // this is what you want
```

and then in your app.js you can do something like

```
var Cat = require('db');

var peter = new Cat();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks zeMirco. so that says that every model is in a diffrent file ?

Comment: that depends on you. You can export multiple models from one file (for example `exports.Cat = Cat` and `exports.Dog = Dog`) or stick with one model per file. For the later I would use a global config file for the database connection params.

Answer (score 7):

You can use exports to define a module that can be required elsewhere:

./models/list.js

```
var ListSchema = new Schema({
    name                : { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
    , description   : { type: String, trim: true }
});

module.exports = db.model('List', ListSchema);
```

./routes/list.js

```
var list = module.exports = {};

var List = require('../models/list');

list.get = function(req, res){
        List.find({ user: user._id }).exec(function(err, lists){
            res.render('lists', {
                lists: lists,
            });
        });
    });
};
```

./app.js

```
app.get('lists', routes.lists.get);
```

Comment: db - where is it defined? is it global?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express, then I would put the models in the app.settings. You can do something like this at config time:

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('db', {
      'main'     : db
    , 'users'    : db.model('User')
  })
})
```

You would then be able to use the models like `req.app.settings.db.users`, or you can create a way to get the `db` var in the file you want in other ways.

This answer is not a complete example, but take a look at my starter project that sets up express and mongoose in a relative easy to use way: https://github.com/mathrawka/node-express-starter

Comment: I think this does not add any value over the standard node/commonjs module system and couples your code to express's configuration system for no reason. Just KISS with commonjs modules.

Comment: Yes, it couples it with express and makes it easier to access common things like mongoose models. For production applications, sometimes the simple methods are not resilient enough.

Answer (score 2):

As an adding to accepted answer, if you want to export multiple modules you can do:

In db.js:

```
var my_schemas = {'Cat' : Cat, 'Dog': Dog};
module.exports = my_schemas;
```

Then in the app.js:

```
var schemas = require('db');
var Cat = schemas.Cat;
var Dog = schemas.Dog;
Cat.find({}).exec({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PersonSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  passowrd: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
  },
  profilepic: {
    type: String,
    default:
      "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1131164548/vector/avatar-5.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=CK49ShLJwDxE4kiroCR42kimTuuhvuo2FH5y_6aSgEo=",
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

// exporting our person schema
module.exports = Person = mongoose.model("myPerson", PersonSchema);
```