# Exporting Mongoose model without waiting for connection 'open' event

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am exporting a Mongoose model and able to use it in other files, but I am confused why it is working. Why do I not need to wait for the connection open event to fire? The [Mongoose getting started tutorial](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html) talks about needing to wait to work with the connection until this event fires. I was about to refactor so that I exported a Promise that would resolve upon firing of the 'open' event, but refrained from complicating things since the below works.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668547/exporting-a-mongoose-database-module) suggests that it is not necessary to wait for the 'open' event.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/XXX');

var db = mongoose.connection;

var listingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
})

var Listing = mongoose.model('Listing', listingSchema);

module.exports = Listing;
```

Comment: This is a "rare" case where it is absolutely true that the age of the answer there ( from 2012 ) actually does matter. The problem is that the underlying MongoDB node driver used changed it's API in recent years. Previously "mongoose" used a method which would establish connections "later" as you used any API actions ( `save()`, `create()` etc ). Whist that "sort of" happens now, the method to establish the connections the old way has been removed. So it's really best practice to "await" the initial connection. It always was "nest" really, but older API "hid it away". Now it does not.

Comment: Also BTW the "modern" approach would be to `await` the `connect()` instead of listening for the `'open'` event anyway.