# Error: Cannot find module '../../models/blog' in my NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is my code in routes/blog.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const Blogs = require("../models/blog");
```

and this my code in models/blog.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const dbUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogDB';

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const blogSchema = new Schema({
id: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId
},
title: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
author: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
category: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
content: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
})

 const Blogs = module.exports = mongoose.model("blogs", blogSchema);
 //module.exports = mongoose.model("blogs", blogSchema);
```

I've tried some basic solutions. But still can't use npm start ,
Is there any way I can get it to work? I'm a beginner, please.

[image: in my path]

Comment: check this out for exporting a model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668547/exporting-a-mongoose-database-module

Comment: It looks like the models folder is nested within the views folder. So either move it out of the views folder or change the import in the routes/blog.js file to `const Blogs = require("../views/models/blog");`

Comment: Thank " Chase Ingebritson" it worked.

Comment: your path of `require` pointed to wrong place, it should be `require("../views/models/blog");`

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes/blog.js` edit 3rd line to this `const Blogs = require("../views/models/blog");` should resolve your problem.